# serialized class instance disappears from session

Tags: php, session, instance-variables

I've made an img editor which works fine in 99.9% of the situations.

However, in that rare 0.1% something weird happends, my session remember doesn't the proper value.

I have this in the page that inits the class:

```
$imgScreen = new img4crop();
// And here some settings like $imgScreen->setExtraJs($extraJs);
```

In this class I have a functions to save the `$this` data to an array:

```
private function save(){
    $_SESSION['cropper'][$this->uniqid] = serialize($this);
}
```

In `init-page.php` I open a fancybox, loading the settings back into the class:

```
$info = unserialize($_SESSION['cropper'][$_GET['id']]);
// Should now be the same as $imgScreen
```

**The problem**
Sometimes `$_SESSION['cropper'][$_GET['id']]` is set to `NULL`. I have no clue why. *This only happens very rarely.* The key is set.
When I debug, and append`echo $_SESSION['cropper'][$this->uniqid];` to the `save()` function, it gives me the value I want it to have.

So, where does my session value go, only in that rare occation? Why isn't it there in the fancybox screen?

**After 1st comment:** It is possible for the init-page to start multiple instances, they each get their own value in `$_SESSION['cropper']`. In the situation above, they all work, just that one doesnt. On reload, I start new instances and the exact same screen doesnt work, even though I now has a new, fresh id

**Edit:** It gets weirder: If the location where the image has a file with the same name as the class will use, there are no problems. Weird part: The whole class has no code regarding to files, apart from the final step (the screen has 3 steps), where I use ImageMagick.
Important to know: When I installed the page where this occurs, the targetfile didn't exist either, started blank.

Comment: Well, it would be NULL if a different session started, wouldn't it?

Comment: No **new** session is started, just continued. All other values in the same `$_SESSION` array remain exactly the same. Just that 1 value.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the whole session?

Comment: Haha, ofcourse, been debugging for some while now.

Comment: Can you reproduce this yourself or are these errors you're seeing from visitors? It might just be a bot trying out different id's, or even a user trying to move incorrectly between sessions.

Comment: Nope. That's very enoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was, as to be expected, a quircky little something unrelated to the actual code:

In my index.php I do `$_SESSION['cropper'] = array();` to reset the array, then let the function which shows an editorscreen set new settings to the cropper, this works perfectly fine.

In that html I have an image with an anti cache:

```
echo '<img src="'.$image_url.'?'.time.'" />';
```

The problem occured when `$image_url` is empty/undefined, resulting in a source something  like the following:  `?1420793438`. It starts with a `?`, so it's effectively calling `index.php?1420793438`.

**And at the beginning of that `index.php` we reset**, resulting in an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

When you are serializing objects you have to make sure you load the base class (prototype) before unserializing the object. For PHP native objects you don't have to do anything, it will load the base classes.

Your variable $this is an instance of a class. In order for $this to exist the base class need to exist. Perhaps it's working most of the time because of an autoloader or the particular sequence you are loading items.

Comment: But when I serialize() $this, save that to a session var and then echo the session var, I get the result string. I can understand this might be wrong, but how can something have a value, and be null the next screen? The error isn't when I (un)serialize/init, the whole session value disapears

Comment: You are trying to save an object across processes. When you unserialize, the same infrastructure needs to be in place as when you serialized in order for it to work properly. Unserialize will work, the object won't. Try a var_dump to see it's true nature.

Comment: but it almost works every time... Things got weirder: There is an image on the page. If manually fill it, the script works, I remove the image, it doesnt work.. I remove the imgtag altogether, and it works again... It's just a plain image, nothing weird about it, not a php with a mime or anything...